# Can i run 2 django projects on 2 domains but on 1 ip?

Tags: django, nginx, virtualhost

I'm trying to run two django projects using nginx using these two configurations:

```
upstream django_project_1 {
    server unix:///home/project_1_user/project_1/project_1.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name project1.com www.project1.com;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/project_1_user/project_1/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/project_1_user/project_1/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django_project_1;
        include     /home/project_1_user/project_1/uwsgi_params;
    }
}

upstream django_project_2 {
    server unix:///home/project_2_user/project_2/project_2.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name project2.com www.project2.com;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /home/project_2_user/project_2/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /home/project_2_user/project_2/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django_project_2;
        include     /home/project_2_user/project_2/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I run `uwsgi --socket project_1.sock --module project_1.wsgi --chmod-socket=666` and it runs my first site, but the second doesn't work with the same comand (yes, i changed the names of .sock and project.wsgi). It runs normally without any errors, but i still can't connect via domain name.
**Do I need to buy an additional IP or can I somehow configure it so that there are two sites and two domains on one IP?**

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple domains on a single IP. In Apache, you use the VirtualHost directive. On nginx, they’re called Server Blocks. It looks like you’re most of the way there, but Digital Ocean has a good tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Are you certain you have A records from your DNS properly pointing to the single IP address for both domains you’re trying to host?